# A problem regarding Permutation Combination

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A soccer coach from a club wants  to arrange an exciting playing team  consisting of 9 attacking players and 2 goal keepers so that the active players attacking the coach determines  the composition of at least 6 attacking players. How many line-ups did the coach want ?

I just could not understand the problem. Can anyone please help me to understand what the coach is exactly trying to do ?

Comment: The "players attacking the coach"? That's new.

Comment: This sounds like it is missing details lost in translation or information specific to soccer needed to complete the problem.  We can tell you how to count mathematical objects who are properly defined... for instance there are $\binom{9}{6}$ ways to choose a subset of six of the attacking players and $\binom{9}{6}+\binom{9}{7}+\binom{9}{8}+\binom{9}{9}$ ways to choose a subset of *at least six* of the attacking players... but whether these are at all related to the intended problem here?  I haven't a clue.

Comment: For all I know, "*determine the composition of*" here is in reference to whether the attackers are playing as center-back, attacking midfield, sweeper, striker, etc... and asking how many ways we can assign explicit specific roles to at least six of the attacking players...

Comment: Yes You are right question is lacking information. This is why , I was having hard time to understand this. @JMoravitz